# How to provide a password over ssh using python script?

Tags: python

sshpass -P mysshpass ssh root@127.0.0.1 "./myscript.py"

Above is the command that I execute from shell, it asks me for a password as "myscript.py" is scripted to ask for it. But when I execute the same command from python, it doesn't prompt me for password.

my python code

os.system(sshpass -P mysshpass ssh root@127.0.0.1 "./myscript.py")

Answer (score 0):

you might consider `paramiko` module, or by specifiying a key file (rsa private key) with `ssh -i` (see `authorized_keys` if you are not familiar with ssh auth

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that allows you to obtain the requested result using pexpect:

```
import pexpect

def ssh(host, cmd, user, password, timeout=30, bg_run=False):                                                                                                 
    """SSH'es to a host using the supplied credentials and executes a command.                                                                                                 
    Throws an exception if the command doesn't return 0.                                                                                                                       
    bgrun: run command in the background"""                                                                                                                                    

    fname = tempfile.mktemp()                                                                                                                                                  
    fout = open(fname, 'w')                                                                                                                                                    

    options = '-q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oPubkeyAuthentication=no'                                                                         
    if bg_run:                                                                                                                                                         
        options += ' -f'                                                                                                                                                       
    ssh_cmd = 'ssh %s@%s %s "%s"' % (user, host, options, cmd)                                                                                                                 
    child = pexpect.spawn(ssh_cmd, timeout=timeout)                                                                                                                            
    child.expect(['password: '])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    child.sendline(password)                                                                                                                                                   
    child.logfile = fout                                                                                                                                                       
    child.expect(pexpect.EOF)                                                                                                                                                  
    child.close()                                                                                                                                                              
    fout.close()                                                                                                                                                               

    fin = open(fname, 'r')                                                                                                                                                     
    stdout = fin.read()                                                                                                                                                        
    fin.close()                                                                                                                                                                

    if 0 != child.exitstatus:                                                                                                                                                  
        raise Exception(stdout)                                                                                                                                                

    return stdout
```

Comment: Seems like you are getting a timeout.

Is the ssh command working from BASH?